# How to upload array to Firestore Data in Android Studio Java

Tags: java, android, arrays, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**I want to upload data like this:**

[image]

**Edited Questions**

```
//I have ArrayList<FoodModel> arr;
ArrayList<FoodModel> arr = new ArrayList<>();
arr.add(new FoodModel("Hamburger"));
arr.add(new FoodModel("Pizza"));
arr.add(new FoodModel("Chicken"));
//and so on...
```

**I want to upload that `ArrayList` to firestore it is Possible?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need add a list field in the hashmap:

```java
Map<String, Object> docData = new HashMap<>();
docData.put("favFoods", Arrays.asList("Hamburger", "Vegetables"));

db.collection("data").document("one")
        .set(docData)
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully written!");
            }
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Error writing document", e);
            }
        });
```

Alternatively, you can also use `arrayUnion` to add new items to an array.

```java
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("col").document("docId");
docRef.update("favFoods", FieldValue.arrayUnion("Pizza"));
```

---

You can add array of objects (and even nested maps) in Firestore. However, you should add the array as a list.

References:

- [Cloud Firestore Data Types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#data_types)
- [Update elements in an array](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array)

Comment: Hello, @Dharmaraj I updated my question please check it out.

Comment: @TonyStark  you can add an array of objects... just put that `arr` in the hashmap. iirc you need to convert it to a list as in the documentation.

Comment: can you please edit your answer as you say in the comment.

Comment: Updated the answer .

Comment: if I want to access it how can I do that?

Comment: @TonyStark please refer to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document). They have sample function there. If you are facing issues with that, I'd recommend asking a new question a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236383/discussion-between-tony-stark-and-dharmaraj).