# How to access array data from Firebase Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firebase Firestore database that looks like this:

[image: image link]

**And I want to store that data in my `ArrayList<>`**

If You are not understanding anything you can check my previous question [**Question Link StackOverFlow**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68916796/16525859)

Comment: So you want to get the content of the `favFoods` array right? Then please show a more detailed database schema and what have you tried so far.

Comment: Yes I want `favFoods` array

Comment: @AlexMamo did you check my previous question because I am asking related to that [question link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68916796/16525859)

Comment: Is this `db.collection("data").document("one")` your structure?

Comment: Yes!. it looks like this `db.collection("fav").document("randomId")`

Comment: Do you have that `randomId` stored in a variable? Then show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236384/discussion-between-tony-stark-and-alex-mamo).

Comment: NO! I mean auto-generated ID by Firestore

Comment: And how would you access that document if you [don't have its ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68916648/is-there-a-way-to-access-the-auto-generate-document-id-from-firestore/68918829#68918829)?

Comment: No! I have the Id that looks like this `xQjHVBm0GtUE4VhP3A6m` randomly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display the of your `favFoods` array, please use the following lines of code:

```
db.collection("fav").document("xQjHVBm0GtUE4VhP3A6m").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            if (document.exists()) {
                List<String> favFoods = (List<String>) document.get("favFoods");
                for (String favFood : favFoods) {
                    Log.d(TAG, favFood);
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

So as you can see, you should call `get()` and cast the object to List. The result in the logcat will be:

```
Chicken
Humburger
vegetables
```